# Generic list match any value

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, list, generics

I'm sure someone has answered this but I'm having trouble finding the correct search terms to locate it...

I can definitely do this by looping through all the values but I'm just checking to see if anyone knows an easier way.

`Dim List1 As New List(Of Integer) From {1,3,5,7}`

```
Dim List2 As New List(Of Integer) From {2,4,6,8}

List1.ContainsAnythingFrom(List2) = False
```

because there are no matching numbers in either list.

```
Dim List1 As New List(Of Integer) From {1,**3**,5,7}

Dim List2 As New List(Of Integer) From {2,**3**,6,8}

List1.ContainsAnythingFrom(List2) = True
```

because there is a 3 in each list.

I'm looking for a **ContainsAnythingFrom** type function.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for the programming language you're asking about.

Comment: Sorry, it's VB.Net.  I can't seem to find where to edit my question or tags.  Found it.

Comment: See a more performant solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812042/check-whether-two-lists-have-at-least-one-common-item/17812043#17812043

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) LINQ method to find common items

```
Dim list1 = New Integer() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Dim list2 = New Integer() {3, 4, 5, 6}
Dim list3 = New Integer() {7, 8}

Dim list1HasAnyOfList2 = list1.Intersect(list2).Any()
' true

Dim list1HasAnyOfList3 = list1.Intersect(list3).Any()
' false
```

Comment: @Aaron: Note that the second list is completely enumerated when you `Intersect`. Therefore, for better performance, it is recommended to have the smaller list as the second parameter. (i.e.`largeList.Intersect(smallList)`).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim l1 As New List(Of String) From {"a", "b", "c", "d"}

    Dim l2 As New List(Of String) From {"e", "f", "c", "d"}

    Dim intersection As IEnumerable(Of String) = l1.Intersect(l2)

    '  Dim result As List(Of String) = l1.Intersect(l2).ToList()

    For Each s In intersection
        Console.WriteLine(s)
    Next
```