# Check whether two lists have at least one common item

Tags: vb.net, performance, list, generics, comparison

If there are two lists:

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of Integer)
list1.AddRange({1, 2, 3})

Dim list2 As New List(Of Integer)
list2.AddRange({1, 4, 5})
```

What is the best way in VB.NET, in terms of performance, to detect whether they have one or more common items? As much as possible this should be generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Function ContainsAny(Of T)(col1 As IEnumerable(Of T), col2 As IEnumerable(Of T)) As Boolean
    ' performance checks
    If col1 Is Nothing OrElse col2 Is Nothing Then Return False
    If col1 Is col2 Then Return True
    ' compare items, using the smallest collection
    If col1.Count < col2.Count Then
        Dim hs1 As New HashSet(Of T)(col1)
        For Each v In col2
            If hs1.Contains(v) Then Return True
        Next
    Else
        Dim hs2 As New HashSet(Of T)(col2)
        For Each v In col1
            If hs2.Contains(v) Then Return True
        Next
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

Code example:

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of Integer)
list1.AddRange({1, 2, 3})

Dim list2 As New List(Of Integer)
list2.AddRange({1, 4, 5})

Dim anyMatch As Boolean = list1.ContainsAny(list2)
```

Comment: With how Contains works, IIRC, it will iterate over all elements to find the one you need, which is very slow. A better way in my opinion would be to iterate once and put the values into a Hashset or a Dictionary (depending on .NET version being used), then use [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx) or [ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) respectively.

Answer (score 2):

In C# (but probably valid in VB as well)

```
list1.Intersect(list2).Any()
```

Comment: How about performance, doesn't this do a full intersect before checking for matching items?

Comment: and performance wise, it shouldn't be a problem, as LINQ is lazy. So as soon as there's one element intersecting, it'll return (provided that Intersect is lazy, and I think it is)

Comment: no, I'm wrong, list1 will be fully iterated before yielding any results